# group python list of objects by 2 attributes

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of objects ie

```
class A:
    int b
    int c
```

so

```
a = A(b=1, c=2)
b = A(b=4, c=2)
...
```

I have a list of these

```
[a, b, c, d, ..., n]
```

How can I sort this list into groups where in each group the objects have equality between two or more attributes of my choosing. So if I had

```
e = A(b=3, c=5)
h = A(b=3, c=5)
```

These will be grouped together into a list or some other structure (set maybe?)

Comment: 1. That *"class definition"* isn't valid Python. 2. If you want to provide a means for determining whether two instances are equal according to your own rules, implement `A.__eq__`. 3. Once you have that, there are plenty of questions on grouping list items already.

Comment: Okay, I was just using that as an example, I am actually dealing with database records where I need to group them by an arbitrary attribute

Comment: Most database client libraries contain a `find` function to assess a particular attribute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

For example:

```
from itertools import groupby

class A(object):

    def __init__(self, b, c):
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


items = [A(1, 2), A(1, 2), A(1, 2), A(2, 2), A(3, 4), A(3, 4), A(5, 6)]

groups = groupby(items, lambda a: (a.b, a.c))

for key, group in groups:
    print "Key: %s, Number of items: %s" % (key, len(list(group)))
```

Output:

```
Key: (1, 2), Number of items: 3
Key: (2, 2), Number of items: 1
Key: (3, 4), Number of items: 2
Key: (5, 6), Number of items: 1
```

So the key function (`lambda a: (a.b, a.c)`) in this case is one that composes `A.b` and `A.c` into a single key (a tuple of both values).

Comment: Is there a way to turn this iterator object into a list object where the individual groups are elements of it?

Comment: @user3667450 you can use a simple list comprehension like `all_groups = [list(grp) for key, grp in groups]`. Note though that the `itertools._grouper` is an iterator that shares its iterable with `groupby()`, so once you've consumed it, the groups are gone. See the comment in the documentation, which also has a more verbose example for exactly this case.